# Design tab doesn't account for status bar spacing

Tags: android-studio-3.0

When running the app, part of the content is hidden behind the phone's status bar.

I've tried to look this up, but I mostly see code on how to hide the phone's status bar, but I don't want to do that; I want to keep the phone's status bar visible.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing Layout Decorations under the "Eye" option shows the status bar so I can do the layout accommodating it. solved